# Is there a better way to shutdown/restart OSX?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, command-line, shutdown, restart

Whenever I want to shutdown/restart OSX I click on the menu, select shutdown, and then click the box for not saving the session, and then click OK. Then there's always at least one program that interrupts the shutdown process.

Is there an easier way to do this? Maybe by using the terminal? I was thinking of `shutdown -h now`, but that way seems kind of "dirty." What are some ways to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using The Terminal Command to Shutdown, Restart and Sleep My Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103571/using-the-terminal-command-to-shutdown-restart-and-sleep-my-mac)

Comment: You can press Option when selecting Shutdown from the Apple menu, this will prevent that the "Are you want to shut down your computer now" window is displayed.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't care about saving the session, you can simply hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⏏</kbd> for Shutdown or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⏏</kbd> for Restart

You can also check out this post ([Disable "Reopen Windows"](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/25/disable-reopen-windows-when-logging-back-in-in-mac-os-x-lion-completely/)) on disabling resume if you don't want that. There is another solution posted [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3193281?start=30&tstart=0) on Apple's forums for disabling the feature by William Donelson (second post by him on the page).

Comment: +1, that's a better answer than mine, I didn't know about those extra key combinations. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @binarybob Thanks, picked them up from some article I read a long time ago, then I wrote them down for reference ;)

Comment: Pressing the power button also brings up the Shut Down confirmation window.

Answer (score 7):

Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⏏</kbd> brings up the shutdown dialog window, which is a bit faster than clicking the Apple menu.

Comment: The funny thing is I didn't actually know this one ;)

Comment: This still can be stopped by an application

Comment: @binary, Where's that up button on macbook pro touch?

Answer (score -1):

This can all be controlled by a Preference. Below is for Mountain Lion, which was changed slightly from Lion:

1. Apple Menu - System Preferences
2. General (under Personal section)
3. Select "Close Windows when quitting an Application" - this makes it so windows don't open when you reopen an app.
4. Now when you shut down (and tell it not to reopen windows on restart) they will not open then - or later.

Answer (score -1):

[Functional](http://www.mednotes.net/about/portfolio/programmer/) is a collection of utilities bringing the basic Mac OS X functions from the Apple menu to your Dock. It is the spiritual companion of ['Hypnotize'](http://www.mednotes.net/about/portfolio/programmer/).

Add the Functional folder as a stack to the Dock, and **Logging Out**, **Restarting**, **Shutting Down** or **Sleeping** your Mac will be just a mouse-click away.

[image]

[image]

A review of **Functional** along with its companion **Hypnotize** can be found [here](http://mac360.com/2012/12/a-free-mac-tool-that-puts-a-logout-restart-shutdown-and-sleep-button-in-the-dock/).

Comment: How does this deal with "Then there's always at least one program that interrupts the shutdown process."