# Terminal command to bring up shutdown dialog?

Tags: terminal, command-line, shutdown

I know how to shutdown a Mac from Terminal, but is there a way to actually bring up the shutdown dialog you get from Apple → Shut Down…?

Comment: Bring the dialog from terminal?

Comment: See http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-103777.html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can send `loginwindow` the `kAEShowShutdownDialog` Apple event:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "loginwindow" to «event aevtrsdn»'
```

The four letter codes for Apple events are listed in `AERegistry.h`. See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103571/using-the-terminal-command-to-shutdown-restart-and-sleep-my-mac/103633#103633) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

Applescript:

```
-- Open  Shut Down Dialog...
-- Save this text as file named shutdown.scpt
tell application "System Events"
    set uiScript to click menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process "Finder"
    set uiScript to click menu item "Shut Down…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process "Finder"
end tell
```

You can run it from Terminal like:

```
osascript shutdown.scpt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Automator script that you can later run from the command line with "open".

You could "Record" in Automator. I guess that would be the easy way, but there might be other problems. Because when you record, Automator actually records mouse pointer movements…