# reboot osx from non apple keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, automation

I want to be able to reboot my mac mini with a wireless keyboard (non apple keyboard) and [not by using terminal/ssh](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103571/using-the-terminal-command-to-shutdown-restart-and-sleep-my-mac). I don't want to pull the power or set a scheduled time - just be able to accelerate the shutdown without using a mouse or trackpad.

Is this possible by using some pre-arranged combination of keyboard commands or shortcuts?

Comment: Close voters - there is a far simpler way than using terminal to do this. Please leave open for those future Googlers who don't want to have to launch Terminal, then type a command, to do such a simple task.

Comment: I've edited out some of the "chit chat" and cleared the close votes. Seems a good question for non mouse, non ssh to me. There might be another dupe, but I don't see one at this point.

Comment: @Tetsujin noted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively to the proposed Terminal commands, you can make your own shortcut key commands, that will work system-wide to shut down or restart your Mac

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts
Add new commands to All Applications for Restart… & Shut Down…
Note that those are ellipses, not 3 full stops [periods].
3 stops will not work.
Copy/paste them from here if you're not sure how to make them.

Choose any key commands you like, but make sure they don't conflict with anything else.

[image]

The slightly odd thing is that once you've done it, the menu itself 'grows' another two commands, without ellipses.

[image]

This doesn't appear to affect anything adversely, it just looks odd.

Comment: There are also lots of third party tools - fast scripts, LaunchBar, etc... that will let you define whatever key chord / combination you want to restart. Lots of options for standard or windows USB keyboard to automate UI on macOS. +1 for the great pictures and explanation

Comment: +1 and you can make the additional entries disappear by applying key commands to those without ellipses. Not sure if any would do, but if you follow Apple's GUI guidelines by using Alt/Option for the non-ellipse ones, it should give you the niceness of using Alt/Option to reveal the other option and otherwise hide them.