# Shutdown mac with kill all processes

Tags: macos, shutdown, reboot

Is it possible to shutdown/restart the Mac completely (processes-wise)? My problem is that I'm having issues with terminating a service (`pkill` and `kill` are not doing the job, I don't know why), and if I shutdown or restart the computer, the processes are still running in the background.

The processes I'm talking about are `catalina` and `tomcat` - manually started Apache services.

Comment: Please be more specific about the processes in question. If you restart your computer, *all* processes do get killed and are restarted as needed. So if there are some specific processes which bother you we need to investigate what actually is executing them.

Comment: @patrix, I updated my post.

Comment: If the tomcat etc tasks are setup correctly killing them should restart them

Comment: Are you asking how to shutdown the Mac or to stop certain processes (stopping process is not shutdown)

Answer (score 3):

Two items are likely wrong:

> - ...the processes are still running in the background.
> - manually started apache processes

Both are probably not so. They have been restarted automatically. To prevent this,

1. Try to kill the process by sending it the TERM signal

   ```
   sudo kill -15 {PID}
   ```
2. Check if your services are restarted automatically by launchd

   ```
   launchctl list | grep tomcat
   ```

   If yes, unload e.g.

   ```
   sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The processes which you mentioned (catalina & tomcat) are not system services. These must have been set to start their daemon when these packages/services are installed and executed for the first time. Please refer this https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-start to get more information on how you can set it to run manually.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is given in my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103571/using-the-terminal-command-to-shutdown-restart-and-sleep-my-mac/103572#103572). However this is not a duplicate as the other question asks about GUI apps.

The command you need is shutdown

e.g. to reboot the machine immediately

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

e.g. to shutdown the machine in 60 minutes

```
sudo shutdown -h +60
```

If tomcat and catalina are setup correctly then they will controlled by a launchd setup (or if less well done a Unix script) that will restart the process(es) when the machine starts up or the process is killed. So running kill on then does kill them but another process will start.