# Why do Macs not save your unsaved work from a 3rd party app during a shutdown?

Tags: macos, mac, shutdown

In Windows, if any app is prompting you to save your work, a shutdown is prevented to save work. However, on macOS, if a 3rd party app (like MS word) prompts you to save your work, macOS just kills the app, thus losing any unsaved work after a shutdown. Why?

Comment: How are you shutting down?

Comment: I tried both from GUI and terminal. @mmmmmm

Comment: OK GUI a dialog box will stop the shutdown and works in the same way as MS Windows  so I think does work. From terminal - then the app does not have time or the control to show a dialog box but should create an autosave file so that no work is lost. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/103571/237 for terminal

Comment: What OS, what version of Word? I don't use Office enough to be sure of that, but if it's not going to auto-save keep any unsaved copy on restart, then the app ought to halt shutdown/restart until you have confirmed or denied the "save before quitting" document dialog. Mac apps all, by default, save any document on quit, whether you saved it or not [unless you specifically switch that function off]. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLBKX.jpg

Comment: My experience with Word is it does auto-saves frequently, into a "temporary" version of the file.  When Word restarts, it says "Hey, I have some unsaved files, shall I open them as they were last auto-saved?" except using more confusing language. **If your Word doesn't, check your settings**.  Regardless, this is not a problem you should have. You should go to each app in turn and manually save before shutdown.  Using 'shutdown' to do a 'find my unsaved files for me' is a lot like using Trash to hold short-term work. (hey I know people who do that).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - tbh, since Apple [& many 3rd parties] switched to this method, I very rarely save anything any more, until I know I'm done with it & ready to file away. Many of the apps I use most frequently don't even have a Save option, they just constantly preserve last-state - everything from Final Cut Pro right down to Notes. The only real 'workflow interruptor' these days for me is Photoshop, which does definitely insist on save or discard.